# Keyboard shortcut for maximize and minimize Rstudio Console

Tags: r, rstudio

In Rstudio you can manually maximize the editor panel by clicking the icon in top-right corner. When executing code, the console will slide into view automatically, but then one has to maximize/minimize the panels manually again. Is there any keyboard shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, add <kbd>Shift</kbd> in between to shortcut when switching to the window.

Example:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> switches to current file,

and 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> maximises Current file

Similarly, 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> switches to Console  and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> maximises Console

Now, 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> switches Files/Help pane,
and 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> maximises Files/Help pane.

Answer (score 1):

As a previous user of RStudio, I have never noticed any keyboard shortcuts to achieve what you ask. RStudio allows you to view the assigned keyboard shortcuts by hovering your mouse over the Graphical User Interface (GUI) component. I have also looked over the following list of shortcuts and have not found what you ask of.

[Shortcut List](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> maximizes the current pane
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> restores all panes.

Answer (score 0):

RStudio v1.0.136 has this option, but you need me map it to some key combo yourself in Tools > Manage Keyboard Shortcuts, the search for Console.